# использование Class в качестве выражения

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

элементарно не могу понять объяснение в учебнике ВЫРАЗИТЕЛЬНЫЙ js

Comment: если учебник плохо объясняет, смените учебник. его либо писал индивид, который мысли формулировать не в состоянии, либо переводил персонаж, обладающим таким же даром

Comment: чтобы понять о чем речь погуглите Анонимные классы. формально тут речь  идет, о том, что `class` можно использовать как ключевое слово (инструкцию) для описания класса, где он указывается с именем. А можно использовать, например, в выражении справа от знака присваивания для создания анонимных классов. Формально тут описывается класс, у которого нет имени, и сразу же создается экземляр. Анонимные классы и функции в настоящее время есть, наверное, в подавляющем большинстве языков. Функции, конечно, более распространены, чем классы.